# DB-like interface from exisiting flat files

Tags: python, sql, database, flat-file

I'm looking for the best way to do something and I'm not sure about the existing technologies that could help me with this.

I've got a huge amount of data stored in flat-files, let's say mainly standard csv files, with or without headers, containing IDs and numbers. These files are spread across different folders, but in a "organized way" (i.e. I know how to parametrise paths, they're not just randomly spread around).

The question is whether there is a way of using these files as if they were a proper DB. That is, I'd like to have an interface where I can query and get replies. Let me give you an example: let's say that I have dated files containing different fields. Each file has a list of IDs, and many entries, say Value A, Value B, Value C, etc. 
For example, I want to know what's Value B for each ID starting with A and in a period between date x and date y. If all data were aggregated in a classic SQL table, I'd query something like

```
SELECT ValueB FROM MY_TABLE WHERE ID LIKE 'A%' AND Date > x AND Date < y;
```

Is there any technology that allows you to do so starting from flat files?
I only need to read from them. These files are automatically generated by other processes and will never need to be edited. On the other hand, new data is added periodically, so I'd like to do this "dynamically". Also, it's be nice (but not essential) if this technology were based upon Python, with which I'm much more familiar.
In this example, I imagine the idea is to have some way of defining "MY_TABLE" through a list of file paths. The table does not exist as a single entity anywhere in the hard drive, but the data are virtually represented as such.

Any help in this direction would be very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: In theory, sqlite virtual tables can do this; a quick Google says that ASPW bindings may be needed.  In practice, if you can bring this data into real Sqlite tables, you'll be well served.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. My impression was that SQLite would store the whole DB in a single giant flat-file though, hence it is recommended only for small projects. Here we are talking about a couple of hundreds Gb, so ideally I'd need something that could select the needed files "on-the-fly" and only open those. Does it make any sense?

Comment: If you have the spare disk space (double or more) to load the data into Sqlite, I'd try that as a first pass.  If you're on Windows, then using the MSFT ODBC text file database driver is also an option; if you have Postgres handy (which is easy to do), then the File FDW (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) is an option.  In any case, you'll have to decide how to map files to tables (there is no magic here, there will be work to do), but many different environments are able to map text files as database files (or import them).

Answer (score 0):

Give a look at [ODBCDrivers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBCDrivers), which state it can use CSV files as datasource.